# how to pass variable to Dockerfile while using gcloud builds submit

Tags: docker, deployment, environment-variables, dockerfile, gcloud

I'm quite new for pretty much everyhing.
Docker.
Gcloud.
Gitlab :D

I need to pass some configuration to my dockerfile.
because angular part should be compiled with different configurations for each env.

i intend to use --substitutions but it seems like i can use it for passing another variable other than:

Only the following built-in variables can be specified with the --substitutions flag: REPO_NAME, BRANCH_NAME, TAG_NAME, REVISION_ID, COMMIT_SHA, SHORT_SHA.
https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/builds/submit#--substitutions

i used --set-env-vars but it is used for gcloud deploy.

so i'm asking while using gcloud build submit how can I pass a key/value pair to my Dockerfile?

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you're using `gcloud builds submit` with a Dockerfile (rather than a configuration file), is that correct?

You're using e.g.

```sh
gcloud build submit ... --tag=[[IMAGE]]
```

If so, I think you're not able to pass values to the container build.

However, there's an alternative (and richer) mechanism that you can use and that's to use a Cloud Build configuration (YAML) file.

You'll need to add `config.yaml` alongside the `Dockerfile` and it should contain something of the form:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
  args:
  - build
  - --build-arg=[[KEY1]]=[[VALUE1]]
  - --build-arg=[[KEY2]]=[[VALUE2]]
  - --tag=[[IMAGE]]
  - .
images:
- [[IMAGE]]
```

> **NOTE** In the above, please replace `[[IMAGE]]` with whatever value you're using for the value of `--tag=[[IMAGE]]` in the command currently.

With `docker build`, it is possible to set so-called [`build-time variables`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg) and this is probably (!) what you want to do. See docker's documentation for [`ARG`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg)

In the above, replace|repeat `--build-arg=` for each `ARG` that you need.